# Using "is" or not

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, tenses, phrase-meaning, conversation

Should I use "is" in the below:

1-Whatever what you dream of, with the hard work you can achieve it.

2-Whatever is what you dream of, with the hard work you can achieve it.

Comment: I think both are correct grammatically.  In both sentences, the dependent clauses follow similar style, i.e., Whatever followed by subject + verb; 'What you do....'; 'What it is....'

Comment: "Whatever you dream of" is sufficient.

Comment: I would go with "Whatever you dream of" or "Whatever it is that you dream of".

Answer (score 0):

I would rework the phrase as a whole. All the following are equally valid:

1. "Whatever you dream of, with hard work you can achieve it"
2. "Whatever it is you dream of, with hard work you can achieve it"
3. "Whatever it is that you dream of, with hard work you can achieve it"

All have the same meaning (one of them may sound better to you for the same reason you prefer longer or shorter sentences in your native language).